# Tracker undefined after installing extra modules openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, codeblocks, opencv-contrib

I am currently trying to have OpenCV working with OpenCV extra modules (especially the tracking module) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04), cmake 3.5.1
I downloaded the version 3.4.5 of OpenCV from https://opencv.org/releases.html and the OpenCV contrib 3.4.5 from https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/releases/tag/3.4.5
Then, I followed the tutorial on the official Documentation of OpenCV for Linux : https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

I created a build directory on openCV and used the command

`cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<openCV contrib/modules> <openCV source directory>`

Everything went fine after this command :

```
 --   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy hdf hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc java java_bindings_generator line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python2 python_bindings_generator reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab viz xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv js matlab ovis python3 sfm xfeatures2d
--     Applications:                tests perf_tests apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         NO
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     GTK+:                        YES (ver 2.24.30)
--       GThread :                  YES (ver 2.48.2)
--       GtkGlExt:                  NO
--     VTK support:                 YES (ver 5.10.1)
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.54)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.0.6)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 2.2.0)
--     HDR:                         YES
--     SUNRASTER:                   YES
--     PXM:                         YES
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      YES (ver 2.2.4)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (ver 56.60.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (ver 56.40.101)
--       avutil:                    YES (ver 54.31.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   
--       base:                      YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       video:                     YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       app:                       YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       riff:                      YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       pbutils:                   YES (ver 0.10.36)
--     libv4l/libv4l2:              NO
--     v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev2.h
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
-- 
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Lapack:                      NO
--     Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.2.92)
--     Custom HAL:                  NO
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /home/pgrisart/Documents/opencv-3.4.5/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.12)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.12)
--     numpy:                       /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.15.1)
--     install path:                lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2/python-2.7
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:                          
--     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.9.6)
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
--     Java wrappers:               YES
--     Java tests:                  YES
-- 
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pgrisart/Documents/opencv-3.4.5/build
```

Then

```
make

sudo make install
```

I had no errors

But when I try a code from the documentation using opencv2/tracking.hpp, I don't have it. I only have opencv2/video/tracking.
If I run the code on https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d2/d0a/tutorial_introduction_to_tracker.html with opencv2/video/tracking , Tracker is undefined.

How should I reinstall the contrib modules in order to get the opencv2/tracking.hpp please? I tried many versions of openCV, and went through many tutorials...

Thank you

Comment: Can you edit your question and add what did the cmake command output?

Comment: Here you go @api55

Comment: Your CMake log looks correct, it should have built the tracking module. How are you compiling your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved !
I didn't know what was wrong with the command line but I downloaded the software cmake with the interface following this tutorial : https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-install-opencv-and-extra-modules-from-source-using-cmake-and-then-set-it-up-in-your-pycharm-7e6ae25dbac5
I removed opencv_features2D which caused problems

then

```
make
sudo make install
```

Everything's working with opencv2/tracking.hpp

Answer (score 0):

1. For tracking examples: -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON
2. For advanced features: -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON
3. Do you need tests? If no: -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF